# Calling batch commands in C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

Very new to C#, creating a small exe that will launch on startup for users, giving them a few options, connect to a terminal server, administration (will be password protected..somehow :) ) and Exit.

Now administration I want to launch Task Manager as another user, so my idea was to call `cmd.exe` with `runas` and launch it. However, I'm not having much luck, my below code just launches `cmd.exe` but none of the arguments I specified with it.

```
private void btnAdministration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
    processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processAdmin.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    processAdmin.Arguments = "runas /user:admin C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe";
    Process.Start(processAdmin);
}
```

Comment: From what I know, cmd.exe will not run their arguments as commands, you need to take stdin of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
private void btnAdministration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string password = "userpassword";
            SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

            foreach(char chr in password) secureString.AppendChar(chr);

            ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
            processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
            processAdmin.Password = secureString;
            processAdmin.UserName = "admin";
            processAdmin.FileName = "taskmgr.exe";
            processAdmin.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
            Process.Start(processAdmin);

        }
```

---

<sup>**What MSDN says about that:**</sup>

<sup>Setting the Domain, UserName, and the Password properties in a ProcessStartInfo object is the recommended practice for starting a process with user credentials.</sup>

<sup>**Note:**</sup>

<sup>Putting the password on a string is not recommended as can be a security concern</sup>

Comment: Did you received a `InvalidOperationException` ? If so, I modified try again

Comment: Well no, but how will it run if I cannot specify a password for that account I want to run it as?

Comment: Is there anyway we can get a prompt to enter the password, I would rather not embed the password in plaintext in my code.

Comment: Of course, you don't know how to ask user input!? Simple change the password variable

Comment: Ofc, I mean, to pass straight through to an encrypted string I can use in the processAdmin.Password call

Comment: Can you say why not, any Exception, or?

Comment: Win32Exception was unhandled, directory name is invalid, pointing at the line: Process.Start(processAdmin);

Comment: If you can, try to not put user password in strings as you said, work directly with `SecureString`

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute runas.exe

```
        ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
        processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
        processAdmin.FileName = "runas.exe"
        processAdmin.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"c:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe\""
        Process.Start(processAdmin);
```